# Django ManyToManyField with model matching the custom through table

Tags: django, django-models

I have a situation similar to the `Membership` example from the Django documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through="Membership")

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

While this works fine to get all `Person`s of a `Group` via `g1.persons` I would like to get all `Membership`s.

Conceptually something like the following:

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Membership, through="Membership")
```

Except that this doesn't work because obviously `Membership` has no foreign key for itself.

Is there a way to set up what I want (i.e. a convenience access to members via `g1.members`)? Or is the only solution to manually go through `Membership.objects.filter(group=g1.pk)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a FK [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```py
class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        Group, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="members"
    )
    ...
```

```
>>> g1 = Group.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> g1.members.all()
```